# All audio disappeared in Ubuntu Studio 21.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, kde

Recently all my audio disappeared in Ubuntu Studio 21.10 with KDE desktop.

It all worked fine until today, and now there is no audio. I installed Kmix and the sound came back, but in the KDE System Settings program it no longer lists any section for Audio, which was there before.

The volume icon had disappeared from the main Panel, but one reappeared after installing Kmix, at which point audio was working again, but just for a short time, as the audio stopped working again after rebooting.

I had tried uninstalling and reinstalling pulseaudio but no change.

I have tried restarting pulseaudio, or using pulseaudio -k to kill it which had worked yesterday when the audio did not come on at bootup, but it had worked okay after that.
Today even that does not work.

What can I do to get back the audio? And to have it listed in the System Settings? And to get back the original icon for sound in the Panel that I had before?

Comment: Did you tried the steps listed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) ?

Comment: I tried going to that link, but it displayed an error: Internal server error. When the website is working again, I shall take a look.

Comment: Try again pls =)

Comment: I eventually found the page I think you meant at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingGuide

Comment: I tried following the instructions in that page, and still have no sound. The audio hardware is all recognised, but still no sound, other than a loud click noise when I log in. I know the speakers and audio hardware is working, it all works in a different distro on the same PC.

The audio hardware is: Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller; and GA104 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI) from an HDMI connection to a TV from an NVidia graphics card. Both the TV and PC soundcard have outputs to the loudspeakers.

Comment: i tried to reproduce the issue, with no luck ;( . you can define the audio output by using these steps.. or try to run a live dvd/usb stick version only for test porpouses.

Comment: I don't know why, but now my sound has returned. I think I was looking at the different HDMI options for the sound output, and clicked on different ones, with no sound coming out, and then back to the first one and the sound returned.

I am still missing the Audio section in the KDE System Settings program, it is not listed, and the original volume control on the Panel is still missing.